# How to code the Simplest BitCoin CPU Miner?

Tags: cpu-mining

How would I go about making the simplest form of a CPU bitcoin miner? I have not been able to find documentation on the whole process...

Comment: This [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273201/bitcoin-calculate-hash-from-getwork-function-how-to-do-it) was asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

If you're fluent in Python, there is a reference RPC miner, written by one of bitcoin's developers: https://github.com/jgarzik/pyminer

Comment: I am looking for a more generic document that explains the steps involved. Thanks for this though :)

Comment: I would say python functions pretty well as pseudo-code

Answer (score 6):

Here, a nice explanation (even if the post is old) http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoin-mining-hard-way-algorithms.html

Answer (score 3):

This is a great tutorial for that, if you are familiar with python:

https://github.com/philipperemy/my-first-bitcoin-miner

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: My answer is in the same still and of the same quality of the others, but I have got a downvote and a comment saying: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed." The other answers are very similar to mine, just show another tutorial. I think this is very, very unfair.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct, in general link-only answers are discouraged but there's no reason that the other answers got upvotes while yours was downvoted. I'm sorry

Comment: does this mine actual bitcoin ? and do you have any links for mining actual bitcoin in javascript?